# JavaFx Slider thumb listener

Tags: java, javafx, slider

I am trying to create a media player using java fx slider. I would like to incorporate the play button with the slider thumb. So when user click on the slider's thumb it will activate the media player to play and the slider will move accordingly when its played. From the documentation the listeners is for the slider and not the slider's thumb. Any suggestion or ideas how the listener can be implemented?

Comment: Don't know why this is re-opened, it's still far too broad ;) What _exactly_ do you want to achieve? Which listeners are you talking about, _exactly_? Do some research (look into styling and how to lookup a node from its style class), apply what you learned and come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Slider control was implemented for that purpose, it might be possible but would require a lot of hacking, Why do you have to limit yourself like that ?

I suggest implementing a simple custom control and styling it like to look a slider, or even better you can add an icon inside the thumb, to indicate the state (Playing / Paused), you can basically do whatever you want with it.

I have written the following example which uses a StackPane as a parent, then uses StackPanes for children (the full-width bar and the progress bar, also the thumb) :

I named the class MediaSlider and it extends StackPane

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class MediaSlider extends StackPane {
    private String main = "#6200ee";
    private String sec = "#c6aee6";
    
    private DoubleProperty value;

    private StackPane thumb;

    private ImageView icon;
    private Image playImage, pauseImage;
    private Runnable onThumbClick;

    private boolean dragged = false;
    
    private Consumer<Double> onSlide;
    private double seek;
    
    public MediaSlider() {
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        setMaxHeight(50);

        value = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

        StackPane bar = createRect(sec);
        bar.maxWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());

        StackPane fill = createRect(main);
        fill.maxWidthProperty()
                .bind(widthProperty().subtract(heightProperty()).multiply(value).add(heightProperty().divide(2)));

        thumb = new StackPane();
        thumb.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        thumb.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        thumb.prefWidthProperty().bind(heightProperty());
        thumb.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.radiusProperty().bind(heightProperty().divide(2));
        circle.setFill(Color.web(main));

        playImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/play.png"));
        pauseImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pause.png"));

        icon = new ImageView(playImage);
        icon.fitWidthProperty().bind(thumb.widthProperty().divide(2));
        icon.fitHeightProperty().bind(thumb.heightProperty().divide(2));

        thumb.getChildren().addAll(circle, icon);
        thumb.setEffect(new DropShadow(10, Color.gray(.0, .4)));
        
        DoubleBinding thumbPos = widthProperty().subtract(thumb.widthProperty()).multiply(value);
        
        thumb.translateXProperty().bind(thumbPos);

        thumb.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            dragged = false;
            thumb.translateXProperty().unbind();
        });
        
        thumb.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            double preX = thumb.getTranslateX();
            double x = e.getX() - getHeight() / 2 + preX;
            seek = x / (getWidth() - getHeight());
            seek = seek > 1 ? 1 : seek < 0 ? 0 : seek;
            thumb.setTranslateX(Math.max(0, Math.min(getWidth() - getHeight(), x)));
            dragged = true;
        });
        
        thumb.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            if(dragged) {
                if(onSlide != null) {
                    onSlide.accept(seek);
                }
            }else if(onThumbClick != null) {
                onThumbClick.run();
            }
            thumb.translateXProperty().bind(thumbPos);
        });

        getChildren().addAll(bar, fill, thumb);

    }

    public void setOnSlide(Consumer<Double> onSlide) {
        this.onSlide = onSlide;
    }
    
    public void setOnThumbClick(Runnable onThumbClick) {
        this.onThumbClick = onThumbClick;
    }

    public void pause() {
        icon.setImage(playImage);
    }

    public void play() {
        icon.setImage(pauseImage);
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value.set(value);
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty valueProperty() {
        return value;
    }

    private StackPane createRect(String color) {
        StackPane res = new StackPane();
        res.maxHeightProperty().bind(heightProperty().divide(5));
        res.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + color + ";-fx-background-radius: 5;");
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then used it in the app in the following way

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.Status;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #e5e5e5");

        // load media
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(getClass().getResource("/song.mp3").toURI().toString()));

        player.setOnReady(() -> {
            player.play();
            player.pause();
        });
        
        // instantiate your custom slider class
        MediaSlider s = new MediaSlider();

        // bind slider position to media position
        s.valueProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            double val = player.getCurrentTime().toSeconds() / player.getTotalDuration().toSeconds();
            return Double.isNaN(val) ? .0 : val;
        }, player.currentTimeProperty()));

        // handle click events
        s.setOnThumbClick(() -> {
            if (player.getStatus().equals(Status.PLAYING)) {
                s.pause();
                player.pause();
                player.seek(player.getCurrentTime());
            } else {
                s.play();
                player.play();
            }
        });

        //handle mouse release after sliding by setting the current time
        s.setOnSlide(v -> {
            player.seek(Duration.seconds(player.getTotalDuration().toSeconds() * v));
        });

        // replay on end of media
        player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> player.seek(Duration.ZERO));

        root.getChildren().add(s);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Here is how it looks :

[image: screenshot from the outcome of the code above]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the suggestion. I gain some insights. With this custom slider, I will not be able to implement features for instance, dragging the slider along the track?

Comment: _would require a lot of hacking_ not really - all that's required is to get hold of the thumb (astonishingly, its style class is not specified in the css reference, so it's a bit hacky to rely it being "thumb"). Everything else is plain fx basics a) styling to use an image dependent on not/playing b) installing event handler to play/pause the player c) appropriate sync of slider value with player currentTime

Comment: @kleopatra that was a pretty generic statement, about beating a javafx control to do something it wasn't implemented to do, while implementing the thing you need can be more straightforward

Comment: @qt.qt you have to add that manually, I believe you can handle mouse drag events on the thumb, will add it into my answer asap

Comment: @qt.qt i have updated my answer to support sliding the slider